# Warning: Array to string conversion al validar usuarios registrados con php

Tags: php, html

Quiero verificar y dar ingreso a otra página cuando un usuario inicie sesión en su cuenta, mas no sé cómo hacerlo. Mi idea era la siguiente:
html:

```html
<form class="caja" method="post" action="InicioSesion.php">

    <h1 class="titulo">Iniciar sesión</h1>

    <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" class="usuario">

    <input type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" class="contraseña">

    <input type="submit" name="entrar" value=" Entrar " class="entrar">

</form>
```

php:

```php
$user = $_REQUEST ['usuario'];  
$pass = $_REQUEST ['contraseña'];  
//variable conexion  
$registros= mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from empleados") or die ("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());  
$reg = ['Usuario'];  
$regi = ['Contraseña'];  
if($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){  
    if ($user == $reg && $pass == $regi) {  
        SesionIniciada.html  
    }  
    else {  
        echo 'Los datos ingresados no están en la base de datos';  
    }  
}  
else{  
    echo ' No se pudo ingresar';  
}  
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

si lo ejecuto, me da lo siguiente:

> Warning: Array to string conversion in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\CuartoSemestre\InicioSesion.php on line 123 Array
> Warning: Array to string conversion in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\CuartoSemestre\InicioSesion.php on line 124 Array

Los datos ingresados no están en la base de datos

Comment: Hay varias cosas mal hechas en tu código, pero, ¿cuáles son las líneas `123` y `124`  del archivo `InicioSesion.php`?

Comment: la verdad no tengo idea, no le he movido nada y ahora solo me da el mensaje: Los datos ingresados no están en la base de datos. En este momento, mis lineas 123 y 124 son: if($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){  
                if ($user == $reg && $pass == $regi) {

Comment: por cierto, ya sé que la linea de "SesionIniciada.html" está mal, no sabía que hacer pero ya lo sé...

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias cosas en tu código. Intentaré enumararlas según las voy viendo y luego te sugiero un código mejorado.

1. Acostumbra a usar siempre la superglobal propia del método que tenga el formulario. Viendo que el `form` tiene el método `post`, entonces usa la superglobal `$_POST` en vez de `$_REQUEST`.
2. Siempre conviene verificar la existencia de los valores, por ejemplo usando un ternario. Así evitas la advertencia *`Undefined index`* y controlas en todo momento el flujo del código.
3. En lugar de `die()` asignaremos un mensaje para tener en todo momento control en el flujo del código. Cabe decir que se debe pasar la conexión en parámetro a `mysqli_error()`. Además estás usando la función antigua.
4. En este punto está el principal problema en tu código actual. Tú estás asignando `$reg = ['Usuario'];` y `$regi = ['Contraseña'];` pero, ¿eso que es realmente? Eso no es más que un array con el valor `Usuario` y otro array con el valor `Contraseña`.
   En este punto se aprecia una comprensión errónea sobre cómo funciona `mysqli`. Los datos de la consulta estarán en el objeto `$reg` que estás creando aquí: `$reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros)` y lo que deberías es usar `$reg` para obtener el valor de la columna `Usuario` y de la columna`Contraseña`. Por un error de compresión parece que intentas hacerlo antes, y sin usar el objeto adecuado que es `$reg`. Es decir, `$reg` es un array con los datos (porque lo obtuviste aplicando `mysqli_fetch_array()` y ahora podrás leer cada columna usando el nombre de la misma (asumo que `Usuario` y `Contraseña`  son nombres de columna en la tabla que estás consultando).
5. ¿Qué significa esto? `SesionIniciada.html` Asumo que lo que quieres en ese caso es hacer una redirección a ese archivo.

Vamos ahora a aplicar todo lo dicho en una propuesta de código.

```
# 1. Usar la superglobal específica
# 2a. Recuperar los datos con un ternario
$user = !empty($_POST ['usuario'])   ? $_POST ['usuario']   : NULL;  
$pass = !empty($_POST['contraseña']) ? $_POST['contraseña'] : NULL;  
# 2b. Verificamos cada variable creada con el ternario
if ($user && $pass) {
    $sql="select * from empleados limit 1";
    if ($registros = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
        #4. Resolvemos el núcelo del problema aquí
        $reg=mysqli_fetch_assoc($registros);
        if ($user == $reg['Usuario'] && $pass == $reg['Contraseña']) {  
            mysqli_close($conexion);
            #5. Hacemos la redirección
            header('Location: SesionIniciada.html');
            exit;  
        } else {
            $outPut="Los datos ingresados no están en la base de datos";
        }  
    } else {
        #3. Pasamos la conexión a mysqli_error
        $outPut = "Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
    }  
} else {
    $outPut="No se enviaron datos desde el form";
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
echo $outPut;
```

Si hay algo que no entiendes, pregunta en comentarios.

Comment: me parece que solo se necesita un `mysqli_close($conexion);` inmediatamente despues de `$reg=mysqli_fetch_assoc($registros);` debido a que el resultado ya lo capturaste en `$reg`.

Comment: #TODO: Las conexiones de MySQL no persistentes y los conjuntos de resultados son automáticamente destruidos cuando un script de PHP finaliza su ejecución. Por tanto, aunque el cierre explícito de conexiones abiertas y la liberación de conjuntos de resultados sean opcionales, se recomienda hacerlos. Así, se devolverán inmediatamente los recursos a PHP y a MySQL, lo que puede mejorar el rendimiento. Para información detalla, véase la liberación de recursos